# translation in fourier space

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I'm attempting to animate a simple sine wave image. Logically, this can be accomplished with a Fourier-space image that has power in exactly 1 real component (pixel), and gradually changing the pixel's corresponding imaginary component (phase value). The code below produces a horizontal grating that very gradually shifts downward. Yet the shift is slow, and once the phase exceeds a certain value, the image no longer animates. What are the phase component's units and range? What am I missing here?

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib as mpimg

f = (np.zeros([33, 33]) + 0j) # blank Fourier image
f[14, 16] = (1 + 0j) # a single component with power

steps = range(16) # number of images to produce
for i in range(len(steps)):
    c = np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(f, axes=[0, 1])) # grating image (cartesian)
    mpimg.imsave('grating %02i.png' % i, c, cmap='gray') # save image
    f[14, 16] += complex(0, 1/16.0) # increment phase
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phase component isn't just the imaginary component.  The phase component is atan2(Im, Re).  To shift the image linearly, your increment should probably modify this phase by 2*pi/nsteps.  Which means it's got to modify both the real and imaginary component.

Comment: That's it! But stated more clearly, first calculate the angle formed between the real and imaginary components with `atan2(Im, Re)`. Then increment the resulting angle by some step value. Finally, replace the original Fourier component with `complex(cos(new_angle), sin(new_angle)`.